# How can I count with @Count filter in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to use the function below to run with the following conditions. I get the error "Value of type 'realmData' has no member 'count'". It is true, but I am trying to find out an alternative to using the .count function to count the number of things in a specific array position. Can I use the .filter Realm command in some way?

```
if 1 <= realmData[0].count {
        tableArray.insert(realmData[0].title, at: 0)
    }
```

Another function that would work for what I am trying to do is

```
realmData[0].title.isEmpty == false {
        tableArray.insert(realmData[0].title, at: 0)
    }
```

When I run it though it says that the index is out of range, I could fix this error if there was a way for me to check if the index is out of range before the function above runs, which is why I use the prior function. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: What type is inside the array

Comment: There are strings inside the array. It is an array of RealmSwift results.

Comment: The @ count is not a filter, it's an aggregate function that operates on a results object to return a count instead of the objects. Your code appears to have already loaded the objects `realmData[0]`; is that a collection object, index 0. More code in needed to provide context of what you're attempting to do. Also, note *number of things in a specific array position* will always be one. A Realm collection has one object per index (there could be sub objects though). Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)